# Open VPN - bridged VPN not responding to ARP requests to clients

Tags: vpn, openvpn, bridge

Recently I've been attempting to build a new Windows Server 2016 Open VPN server to replace an older, outdated PPTP VPN that we currently have in place.

I've had some success, and I've managed to get a routed VPN working but this creates another potential dilemma for us with site-to-site VPN's we currently have in place and with correctly setting routing.

Instead I've tried to set the VPN as a bridged VPN instead. I've bridged the TAP and Ethernet adaptors and I've updated the config. The client can now connect to the bridged VPN and can ping/RDP to the VPN server (192.168.54.176) but cannot access the rest of the network.

Using Wireshark, I've determined that the ping requests are being properly redirected to the network, however other servers on the network are unable to respond. This appears to be because ARP requests for the VPN client IP (192.168.55.75) are not getting any form of response. I'm not exactly sure how it should work, but the server is neither responding to the requests to give the other servers on the network something to reply to, or forwarding them on to the connected client.

I'm not sure if I've overlooked something, or if more configuration is needed, but it definitely feels as if something is missing. Any help is certainly appreciated!

Open VPN config:

```
port 1194

proto udp

dev tap


ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.key"

dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh2048.pem"

topology subnet

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

server-bridge 192.168.54.176 Subnet 192.168.55.75 192.168.55.80

push "route 192.168.48.0 Subnet"

push "redirect-gateway autolocal def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS Server"
push "dhcp-option DNS Another Server"

client-to-client
keepalive 10 120

cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun

verb 3

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Answer (score 1):

After several days of trial and error, I've finally managed to find the source of the problem!

The VPN server is a Windows VM on a Hyper-V host. Whereas most instances of Open VPN appear to be Linux on VMware. I'd seen frequently that VMware Open VPN servers need to be set to promiscuous mode to allow them to broadcast on different MAC addresses, however I'd never seen similar instructions regarding Hyper-V so never put much thought to it.

Eventually, I checked Hyper-V and found the "Enable MAC address spoofing" setting under VM settings > Network Adapter > Advanced Features. This setting must be enabled to allow the Open VPN server to forward ARP requests on behalf of connected clients.

Comment: This is well known feature of a hyper-v. To my knowledge, it is the only one hypervisor that has such settings, and I never heard it helped anyone or made things better, but to the contrary I constantly see it makes things harder and keeps frustrating people.